# Sending EWS invites with Viewpoint via heroku dyno get blocked by spam filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, calendar, exchange-server, spam

I'm using the excellent [Viewpoint](https://github.com/WinRb/Viewpoint) ruby gem to create an event in my EWS calendar and send invites to attendees, on an heroku app.

This works very well in development, and in heroku production console.

When I do it from an heroku web dyno, the event gets created with correct attendees, but invites are not sent. Instead, I receive an email from exchange server saying my outbound message can't be delivered due to spam detection:

```
Remote Server returned '550 5.1.8 Access denied, spam abuse detected'
En-têtes de message d'origine :

Authentication-Results: gmail.com; dkim=none (message not signed)
 header.d=none;
Received: from AMSPR01MB103.eurprd01.prod.exchangelabs.com (10.242.91.146) by
 AMSPR01MB101.eurprd01.prod.exchangelabs.com (10.242.91.140) with Microsoft
 SMTP Server (TLS) id 15.1.154.19; Mon, 4 May 2015 09:18:41 +0000
Received: from AMSPR01MB103.eurprd01.prod.exchangelabs.com ([169.254.4.13]) by
 AMSPR01MB103.eurprd01.prod.exchangelabs.com ([169.254.4.13]) with mapi id
 15.01.0154.018; Mon, 4 May 2015 09:18:40 +0000
Content-Type: application/ms-tnef; name="winmail.dat"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
From: Nicolas Marlier <nicolas@marlier.onmicrosoft.com>
To: "nmarlier@gmail.com" <nmarlier@gmail.com>
Subject: =?utf-8?B?Tm91dmVsIMOpdsOobmVtZW50?=
Thread-Topic: =?utf-8?B?Tm91dmVsIMOpdsOobmVtZW50?=
Thread-Index: AdCGSDTEah5PWrxeqEy/iSmi4R7oNg==
X-MS-Exchange-MessageSentRepresentingType: 1
X-MS-Exchange-Calendar-Originator-Id: 52a7b57c-9423-417c-8560-37fa3ae0e74a;/o=ExchangeLabs/ou=Exchange
 Administrative Group
 (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=096fdd7902e244399c6fbd8bf2401533-nicolas
Date: Mon, 4 May 2015 09:18:40 +0000
Message-ID: <AMSPR01MB10304E80D885534965D74C3F7D20@AMSPR01MB103.eurprd01.prod.exchangelabs.com>
Accept-Language: fr-FR, en-US
Content-Language: en-US
X-MS-Has-Attach:
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator: <AMSPR01MB10304E80D885534965D74C3F7D20@AMSPR01MB103.eurprd01.prod.exchangelabs.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Originating-IP: [54.163.190.73]
Return-Path: nicolas@marlier.onmicrosoft.com
X-Microsoft-Antispam: UriScan:;BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:;SRVR:AMSPR01MB101;
X-Microsoft-Antispam-PRVS:
    <AMSPR01MB10156182A79CE60E68A4106F7D20@AMSPR01MB101.eurprd01.prod.exchangelabs.com>
X-Exchange-Antispam-Report-Test: UriScan:;
X-Exchange-Antispam-Report-CFA-Test:
    BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:(601004)(5005006)(3002001);SRVR:AMSPR01MB101;
X-Forefront-PRVS: 05669A7924
```

I'm thinking this may be caused by the heroku instance not being whitelisted, and I'm considering trying something like the Proximo add-on to fix that. Any thought on another way to make sure the invite is being sent ?

Comment: Hey, Nico. Have you found the fix for this by any chance? We faced with the same issue when trying to send emails from Heroku environment.